# how to iteratively move files/folder using grep pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to iteratively move the code files/folders from one directory to another as part of the continuous integration and for that, I am using the below code block.

```
for i in $HOME/gitstage/frolit/* ; do 
    if [ echo "$i" | grep -v '*db.sqlite3*|*bitbucket-pipelines.yml*' ]; then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Here I am trying to restrict two files db.sqlite3 and bitbucket-pipelines.yml from moving into the destination directory. But somehow this is not working out. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Check out the bash man page for how `if` constructs are used, and `man test` to see what you're actually doing with the `[` command. Consider whether you want to write your CI tools to be POSIX compliant, or if you want to depend on bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash 3.0 or newer:

```
if [[ ! "$i" =~ .*(db.sqlite3|bitbucket-pipelines.yml).* ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $HOME/gitstage/frolit/* ;
do
if [[  "${i}" = *"db.sqlite3"* ]] || [[ "${i}" = *"bitbucket-pipelines.yml"* ]];
then
continue
fi
mv  $i   /target/directory  ####target directory  where   you want  to move the   files to
done
```

This should   work fine in both bash and  ksh even  in older versions. Just  make   sure to  check  for if syntax with your shell and modify above if accordingly.

Comment: Explain your answer

Comment: This   script  will move all the file  from directory
    $HOME/gitstage/frolit/ to target directory except the files having db.sqlite3  and  bitbucket-pipelines.yml  in their names